# scrapy, how to send multiple requests to a form

Tags: python, forms, web-scraping, scrapy

I have working code here. I am sending 1 request to a form, and I am getting back all the data that I need. Code:

```
 def start_requests(self):
    nubmers="12345"
    submitForm = FormRequest("https://example.com/url",
                             formdata={'address':numbers,'submit':'Search'},
                             callback=self.after_submit)
    return [submitForm]
```

Now, I need to send multiple requests through the same form, and collect the data for each request. I need to collect the data for x numbers. I stored all numbers into a file:

```
   12345
   54644
   32145
   12345
```

code:

```
def start_requests(self):
    with open('C:\spiders\usps\zips.csv') as fp:
        for line in fp:
            submitForm = FormRequest("https://example.com/url",
                                formdata={'address':line,
    'submit':'Search'},callback=self.after_submit,dont_filter=True)
    return [submitForm]
```

This code works, but it also collects data for the last entry in the file only. I need to collect the data for each row/number in the file. If I try yield instead, it returns scrapy, stops, and throws this error:

```
if not request.dont_filter and self.df.request_seen(request):
exceptions.AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'dont_filter'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you definitely need `yield` to "fire" up multiple requests:

```
def start_requests(self):
    with open('C:\spiders\usps\zips.csv') as fp:
        for line in fp:
            yield FormRequest("https://domain.com/url",
                              formdata={'address':line, 'submit':'Search'},
                              callback=self.after_submit,
                              dont_filter=True)
```

Also, you shouldn't enclose the `FormRequest` into a list, just yield the request.

Comment: Eh...I usually don't enclose into list I am not sure why I did this time :) Thanks!