# Avoiding overlapping of responses in python scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, screen-scraping, scrapy

I was trying to scrape the family information of Indian Rajya Sabha members found here http://164.100.47.5/Newmembers/memberlist.aspx
Being a newbie in scrapy, I followed [this](https://github.com/AmbientLighter/rpn-fas/blob/master/fas/spiders/rnp.py) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23049375/scrapy-how-to-send-multiple-requests-to-a-form) example codes to produce the following.

```
def parse(self,response):

    print "Inside parse"
    requests = []
    target_base_prefix = 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView2$ctl'
    target_base_suffix = '$lkb'

    for i in range(2,5):
        if i < 10:
            target_id = "0"+str(i)
        else:
            target_id = str(i)

        evTarget = target_base_prefix+target_id+target_base_suffix

        form_data = {'__EVENTTARGET':evTarget,'__EVENTARGUMENT':''}

        requests.append(scrapy.http.FormRequest.from_response(response, formdata = form_data,dont_filter=True,method = 'POST', callback = self.parse_politician))

    for r in requests:
        print "before yield"+str(r)
        yield r


def parse_pol_bio(self,response):

    print "[parse_pol_bio]- response url - "+response.url

    name_xp = '//span[@id=\"ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_ctl02_Label3\"]/font/text()'
    base_xp_prefix = '//*[@id=\"ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TabContainer1_TabPanel2_ctl00_DetailsView2_Label'
    base_xp_suffix='\"]/text()'
    father_id = '12'
    mother_id = '13'
    married_id = '1'
    spouse_id = '3'

    name = response.xpath(name_xp).extract()[0].strip()
    name = re.sub(' +', ' ',name)

    father = response.xpath(base_xp_prefix+father_id+base_xp_suffix).extract()[0].strip()
    mother = response.xpath(base_xp_prefix+mother_id+base_xp_suffix).extract()[0].strip()
    married = response.xpath(base_xp_prefix+married_id+base_xp_suffix).extract()[0].strip().split(' ')[0]

    if married == "Married":
        spouse = response.xpath(base_xp_prefix+spouse_id+base_xp_suffix).extract()[0].strip()
    else:
        spouse = ''

    print 'name     marital_stat    father_name     mother_name     spouse'
    print name,married,father,mother,spouse

    item = RsItem()
    item['name'] = name
    item['spouse'] = spouse
    item['mother'] = mother
    item['father'] = father

    return item



def parse_politician(self,response):

    evTarget = 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TabContainer1'
    evArg =  'activeTabChanged:1'
    formdata = {'__EVENTTARGET':evTarget,'__EVENTARGUMENT':evArg}

    print "[parse_politician]-response url - "+response.url

    return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(response, formdata,method = 'POST', callback = self.parse_pol_bio)
```

**Explanation**
The `parse` method loops over the target id for different politicians and sends requests.
`parse_politician` - for tab changing purpose
`parse_politician_bio` does the scraping of dependency names.

**Problem**
Problem is that this causes duplicate responses to parse_politician_bio.
i.e Information about same person is coming multiple times.
The nature of duplicate responses are quite random at each run i.e - different politicans data may be duplicated at each response.
I have already checked whether there are any request being yield multiple times but none are.
Also tried to put some sleep after each yield request to see if it helps.
I suspect the scrapy Request Scheduler here.

Is there any other problem in the code??Can anything be done to avoid this?

**EDIT**
Just to clarify something here, I know what dont_filter=True does and have deliberately kept that.

The problem is that some response data are getting replaced. For example, when I generate 3 requests, for target_id = 1,2,3  separately. Response for target_id = 1 is getting replaced by a response for target_id = 2 .
*[So that makes me have one response for target_id - 3 and two for target_id -2]*

**Expected output (csv)**

```
politician name , spouse name , father name , mother name
pol1 , spouse1, father1, mother1
pol2 , spouse2, father2, mother2
pol3 , spouse3, father3, mother3
```

**Output given (csv)**

```
politician name , spouse name , father name , mother name
pol1 , spouse1, father1, mother1
pol1 , spouse1, father1, mother1
pol3 , spouse3, father3, mother3
```

Comment: verbal descriptions of a problem can be hard to understand for readers that aren't working with the data. That is why it is considered good practice to include sample (small!) inputs, and the required output from that sample. Your case is a little more complex, but without seeing what this looks like, it may be difficult for others to help. Can't you keep any array of `already_retrieved[@id]`, and test if current id is in `already_retrieved[]`? (Don't know python syntax that well, but I'm sure that sort of thing is possible). Good luck!

Comment: @shellter - Hi, Thanks but I never wanted to filter duplicates. I was curious to know why responses were duplicated. Sorry, my bad - didnt use the correct wordings. Edited the question and added expected and actual outputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally fixed it (phew!).
By default scrapy sends 16 requests at a time (concurrent requests).
Putting the `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 1` in settings.py file made that sequential and solved the issue.

The requests I gave were similar (check above), and the responses data got overlapped with 
one another to give duplicate responses of one type only.

No idea how that was happening though, but the solution by making sequential requests confirms this.
Any better explanations?